# Store json string in txt file or database

Tags: json, list, api

Suppose we are getting lots of list data in `json` format, for every single day the api returns the same data.
Now if I apply the filter on the `json` then where can I store the API `json` result for the current day so that there is no need to call the API multiple times.

How can I store it in a txt file or in a database or maybe in cache?

Comment: _..where we can store api json result..._ in the database?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your aims. You may use a text file or the DB field.
You may use a Redis as a cache.

Try to start with text file at first. Probably it will help you.

1) Draft usage of text (.json) file.

```
// $json = json_encode($array); // if you don't have json data
$filePath = sprintf('%s_cache.json', date('Y-m-d'));
file_put_contents($filename, $json);
```

2) Usage of JSON in MySQL

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (JSON_OBJECT("key", "value")); // something like this
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('{"key": "value"}'); // or this one
```

More details about MySQL are here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html